# Is it possible to rename a Hashmap key?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm looking for a way to rename a Hashmap key, but i don't know if it's possible in Java.

Comment: Gosh, I hope not. Deleting and reentering the key/value pair seems like the way to go. Note that you normally just handle references in the map itself anyway.

Comment: Please don't modify the key of a hash entry! If you're lucky, you'll change it to something with the same hashcode and you'll just go somewhat crazy trying to figure out what happened; if you're unlucky, you'll end up with an entry that can't be found (well, not until the next rebuild of the whole table). Remove/reinsert is much saner, and should be pretty cheap (it's all references, after all).

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Try to remove the element and put it again with the new name. Assuming the keys in your map are `String`, it could be achieved that way:

```
Object obj = map.remove("oldKey");
map.put("newKey", obj);
```

Comment: +1. And simplest to read is `map.put( "newKey", map.remove( "oldKey" ) );` and provided contains `oldKey`

Comment: As far as readability is concerned, I quite disagree, I personnally prefer to see clearly that an object is removed from the map, and then added. And since the OP seems to be pretty new to Java, I decided to put it that way. For the sake of performance however, your version is of course prefered (since I don't think the compiler will optimize my version your way).

Comment: For javac 1.8.0_45, the one-line version is two bytecodes shorter, which surprised me.  More annoyingly with generics you can't pass `obj` to `put` without casting it or declaring it as another type, but of course passing the result of `remove` directly works.

Answer (score 30):

```
hashMap.put("New_Key", hashMap.remove("Old_Key"));
```

This will do what you want but, you will notice that the location of the key has changed.

Comment: @Vins revisit the documentations please :D, remove() will return the object, check this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_remove.htm

Comment: my bad,  I have removed my comment and voted for it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 21):

Assign the value of the key, which need to be renamed, to an new key. And remove the old key.

```
hashMap.put("New_Key", hashMap.get("Old_Key"));
hashMap.remove("Old_Key");
```

Answer (score 13):

You cannot rename/modify the hashmap `key` once added.

Only way is to delete/remove the `key` and insert with new `key` and `value` pair.

***Reason*** : In hashmap internal implementation the Hashmap `key` modifier marked as `final`.

```
static class Entry<K ,V> implements Map.Entry<K ,V>
{
    final K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K ,V> next;
    final int hash;
    ...//More code goes here
}
```

For Reference : [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V))

Comment: this is the best answer in my opinion since it's *not* possible to rename a key.

Answer (score 4):

You don't rename a hashmap key, you have to insert a new entry with the new key and delete the old one.

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue the essence of hasmap keys are for index access purposes and nothing more but here's a hack: making a key-wrapper class around the value of the key so the key-wrapper object becomes the hashmap key for index access, so you may access and change key-wrapper object's value for your specific needs:

```
public class KeyWrapper<T>{

      private T key;
      public KeyWrapper(T key){
         this.key=key;
       }

      public void rename(T newkey){
              this.key=newkey;
       }

}
```

Example

```
   HashMap<KeyWrapper,String> hashmap=new HashMap<>();
   KeyWrapper key=new KeyWrapper("cool-key");
   hashmap.put(key,"value");
   key.rename("cool-key-renamed");
```

Though you could also have a non existing key be able to get the value of an existing key from the hashmap but I fear it might be criminal, anyways:

```
public  class KeyWrapper<T>{

        private T key;
        public KeyWrapper(T key){
            this.key=key;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return hashCode()==o.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash=((String)key).length();//however you want your hash to be computed such that two different objects may share the same at some point
            return hash;
        }
    }
```

Example

```
HashMap<KeyWrapper,String> hashmap=new HashMap<>();
KeyWrapper cool_key=new KeyWrapper("cool-key");
KeyWrapper fake_key=new KeyWrapper("fake-key");
hashmap.put(cool_key,"cool-value");
System.out.println("I don't believe it but its: "+hashmap.containsKey(fake_key)+" OMG!!!");
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case had a map containing not real key -> real keys, so I had to replace the not reals with the reals in my map (the idea is like others)

```
getFriendlyFieldsMapping().forEach((friendlyKey, realKey) ->
    if (map.containsKey(friendlyKey))
        map.put(realKey, map.remove(friendlyKey))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look below points:

1. No,You can not rename the `key` of `HashMap` once added.
2. Very first you have to delete or remove that `key` and then you can insert with new `key` with `value`.
3. Because in `HashMap` internal implementation the `HashMap` key modifier  is `final`.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if instead of Java native HashMap you'll use a **Bimap**.
It's not the traditional Map implementation, and you need to make sure it's suits your needs.

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the
>   uniqueness of its values as well as  that of its keys. This constraint
>   enables bimaps to support an "inverse view", which is another  bimap
>   containing the same entries as this bimap but with reversed keys and
>   values.

Using a bimap, you can inverse the view and replace the key.
Checkout both Apache Commons [BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html) and Guava [BiMap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap).