# Java: Multiple keys, one value HashMap, pointing to the exact same value

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

I'm looking for a way to map multiple keys to the same value without using extra memory by adding this value twice. Normally you would just do:

```
 Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put(065,600);
 map.put(070,600);
```

But it is my understanding that the value 600 is now stored in memory twice. Is there a way to avoid this such that they point to the exact same value? Thanks a bunch ! Peace out

Comment: How memory-consuming do you think is a integer object? Is this too premature?

Comment: You can change your map to this : ``Map<List<Integer> , Integer>``

Comment: It is to store a huge matrix with integers, where lots of integers are the same value. I'm creating a data structure that can cope with this type of matrices.

Comment: "Just do it". Create an `Integer` object and then use it.

Comment: If you're storing a huge list of `Integer` something is wrong. Consider using `int[]`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511703

Comment: Going wild here, but there's a way to parametrize the high value of the integer cache beyond byte range (see the `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high` property). Would not recommend at all, just worth mentioning :)

Comment: But a ---pointer--- reference take 4 bytes anyway...

Comment: @SchiduLuca This seems promising. Is it possible to iteratively increase List<Integer> when new values arrive? Then this should work..

Comment: You can but that's not a very good. Overall it's a bad idea to use mutable variables as keys in a map. I thought that you have an initial list and it will not change after that.

Comment: @user3343378 `IdentityHashMap` maybe?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766906/

Comment: @user202729 The problem I'm trying to solve involves a huge matrix 100,000x100,000 that has for instance only 20 distinct values in total. I'm trying to figure out how to reduce the size of this matrix, by just keeping the 20 distinct values together with location indices of where these values are located on the matrix. Do you think my way of doing it could reduce the size?

Comment: Why can't you use `int[][]`? / ... Yes.

Comment: If I use int[][], I would first have to initialize the array at dimension 100,000x100,000 so memory will be allocated immediately, I thought. I'm trying to reduce memory requirement to less than that..

Comment: Maybe it's not possible how I imagined to do it, but basics of java are a bit lacking from my side

Comment: ... But ... it seems that you're asking the wrong question. If you don't "allocate memory immediately" but still need to store the data at some point in time, you need to allocate memory anyway. How can you avoid doing that?

Comment: Well I was thinking that if you have for instance 1 matrix with everywhere the same value, you can reduce memory by just saying 1 integer and the number of times it occurs instead of storing all integers. To the same extent, I thought that if you have several countable numbers occurring repeatedly in a matrix, you don't actually have to store all of them in memory.. No?

Comment: You're lacking some basic Java knowledge. On typical implementation, a `int` take no more memory than a pointer (reference). And a `HashMap` node definitely cost more memory than two references.

Comment: Hmm, so no way to reduce a huge matrix with lots of same values?

Comment: @user3343378 Arithmetic encoding maybe? 20 different values, each take 4.32 bits, 1e10 values are 5GiB. (if you use `int[][]` each `int` take 32 bits so it's 37GiB, and with HashMap it's definitely larger) What exactly are you trying to do with such a large matrix?

Comment: Alternatively, if there is a value that occur much more often than other values (say, `0`), use a hashmap is reasonable. (sparse array) Although this is getting off-topic.

Comment: I'm just facing memory constraints to fit a matrix in memory. 20 was just an example, the real number of distinct values present in the matrix depends on user settings of the program.. I looked at arithmetic encoding, I'm gonna check this out, this seems a good idea! Thanks!

Comment: And yes, this is a sparse array as well. It is firstly sparse, and secondly the values != 0 that will be in there will also be very unevenly distributed; some occur very frequently, some don't.

Comment: Can't you use some linear algebra for this? It's ages since I don't see such techniques being used, but maybe you could use the SVD (single value decomposition)? See [here](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=82209f7b8bc7c143f4419238ef16c129) for details.

Comment: Speed for creating this matrix is very important, and secondly, a lookup in the original matrix of an element needs to be very rapidly as well. I believe complexity of SVD is an issue here, no?

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember SVD complexity. However, I think you can't have both speed and little memory consumption. Choose to optimize either one or the other. If you use SVD with orthogonal matrices, maybe you could manage to get an acceptable trade-off by using `BitSet` to represent the orthogonal matrices and an array or `List` for the singular values. But I'm just guessing, you should ask specifically about this.

Comment: Alright, will consider this.. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
 Integer i = 600;
 map.put(065,i);
 map.put(070,i);
```

Comment: Suggest using `Integer.valueOf`. That will use the cache whenever possible (IIRC).

Comment: Or just autoboxing.

Comment: Aha, I'm going to try this.

Comment: Am gonna count this as a correct answer as it does exactly what i asked, but following the conversation above, unfortunately, it will not solve my problem :) I'll have to come up with another tactic! Thanks for the help !